# Django Database Routers error: "need more than 1 value to unpack"

Tags: python, django

When I did this in my code:

```
DATABASE_ROUTERS = [
    'some_value_here'
]
```

I got:

```
ValueError at /
need more than 1 value to unpack
<some-path>/django/v1_2/core/handlers/base.py in get_response
```

```
# Setup default url resolver for this thread.
urlconf = settings.ROOT_URLCONF
urlresolvers.set_urlconf(urlconf)
resolver = urlresolvers.RegexURLResolver(r'^/', urlconf)
# Apply request middleware
for middleware_method in self._request_middleware:
    response = middleware_method(request) ...     #<<<<  Error is on this line
    if response:
        return response
if hasattr(request, "urlconf"):
    # Reset url resolver with a custom urlconf.
    urlconf = request.urlconf
```

What's going on? Any ideas?

Comment: How do you know it's the `DATABASE_ROUTER` setting?  What's the error/traceback you're seeing?

Comment: @sdolan: I know because when I remove it, it works. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scratch that, I just the error myself: I need the module name, not just the class name.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
DATABASE_ROUTERS = [
    'some_value_here',
]
```

Comment: Tried it with the comma, no difference. The comma only makes a difference for tuples, anyway.